# How to Remove the Option to Add Users as Superusers to a Group in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

In my Wagtail project, I have a group that is allowed to add new users to the system. However, users belonging to this group can add others as superusers. How can I disable the option for this group to add users as superusers?

Remove Admnistrador
[image]

my forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from wagtail.users.forms import UserEditForm, UserCreationForm

class CustomUserFormMixin:
    journal = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Journal.objects, required=False, label=_("Journal"))
    collection = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Collection.objects.filter(is_active=True), required=True, label=_("Collection"))



class CustomUserEditForm(CustomUserFormMixin, UserEditForm):
    ...


class CustomUserCreationForm(CustomUserFormMixin, UserCreationForm):
    ...
```